# How to echo returning array

Tags: php, arrays

I googled about a function how to convert hex to rgb color code

```
<?php
function html2rgb($color)
{
    if ($color[0] == '#')
        $color = substr($color, 1);

    if (strlen($color) == 6)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[1],
                                 $color[2].$color[3],
                                 $color[4].$color[5]);
    elseif (strlen($color) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[0], $color[1].$color[1], $color[2].$color[2]);
    else
        return false;

    $r = hexdec($r); $g = hexdec($g); $b = hexdec($b);

    return array($r, $g, $b);
}
?>
```

I can't access the data like this echo html2rgb('#cccccc'); because it's an array

// Edit I just want to say thanks to the guys how answered. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can access it like this:

```
$rgb = html2rgb('#cccccc');
$r = $rgb[0];
$g = $rgb[1];
$b = $rgb[2];
```

and then

```
echo "Red = $r, Green = $g, Blue = $b";
```

or just `var_dump($rgb)` or `print_r($rgb)`

Answer (score 1):

try `print_r(html2rgb('#cccccc'));`

This should help you understand: [What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

Comment: Okey i have Array ( [0] => 204 [1] => 204 [2] => 204 ) but how to echo every one of them

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd want something more along the lines of:

```
$cc = html2rgb('#cccccc');
echo "[".$cc[0].",".$cc[1].",".$cc[2]."]";
```

Comment: echo "[$cc[0], $cc[1], $cc[2]]"; <-- Would be better