# Fetch value of one text box and print to a div name "output" with a click of button with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('s1').onclick=function()
{
var value1 = document.getElementById('input').value;
var aj;
if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    aj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    aj=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
aj.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(aj.readyState==4 && aj.status==200)
    {

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=aj.responseText;
    }
}
aj.open("GET","tstprinajax.php?name="+value1,true);
aj.send();
}
</script>
```

This is not working for me. I want to fetch value of one text box and print to a div name "output" with a click of button with AJAX.

HTML code:

```
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="s1"></button>
<div id="output"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

tstprinajax.php:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["name"];
print "<font size='+6' color='#FF0000'>$q</font>";
?>
```

Comment: `print`? Do you mean `echo`?

Comment: Font tags are deprecated. Stop coding like you live in the 90's.

Comment: @PaulS.: PHP also has `print`, which [does much the same thing as `echo`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php).

Comment: print and echo do the same thing @Paul S

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that the page is getting refreshed, because the [default `type` of a `button` element is `submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type), and so the form containing the button is being submitted (to the same page). Change your `button` element to:

```
<button id="s1" type="button"></button>
```

If I hardcode the server response (since JSBin doesn't let me actually do server-side handling, and fair enough), making that change makes your code work:

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ewoqoh/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ewoqoh/1/edit)

In contrast, *without* the `type="button"`, you get a page refresh instead: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ewoqoh/2)

Comment: @VishavdeepSingh: It should do, I've replicated both the problem and the solution successfully, see the edit.

Comment: what ever i type in text box it prints "the response". but i want to print what i type. @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @VishavdeepSingh: Of course it does, as I said, I hardcoded the response. But provided your PHP works, adding `type="button"` to the `button` element should make the text show up.