# ajax call with a return json never catch in success

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a variable from my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert",
    data: { title:title, start:dstart, end:dend },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       data = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log('data = '); // is showing the data with double quotes
           console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and there is my PHP:

```
$id = $calendar->getId();
$json = array ( 'id' => $id );
var_dump(json_encode($json));
json_encode($json);
```

And with my `var_dump` I can see my `json_encore`, like that for example:

```
string '{"id":156}' (length=10)
```

but in my `ajax()` success, `console.log()` don't show anything in my console.

Where can I see if my `success: function(data)` is empty or not ? I would just catch the id in my ajax success.

UPDATE : issue fixed. in fact i'm working with symfony, and I haven't seen that on my action insert where is my PHP, the page called by symfony (indexSuccess.php) was not empty which was why its not working at all.)

Comment: do echo json_encode($json); in your php and check for the response

Comment: $.ajax automatically parses returned data as json if `type: 'json'` is set. so you won't need to `JSON.parse(data)` - just access data like any other object ...

Comment: @Deepu echo json_encode($json) is the same as var_dump(json_encode($json) no ? and where can i check the response ? on the php file ?

Comment: have you tried, `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: You should 'echo' back your result in php file

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at your PHP code, you're basically doing nothing with the output of json_encode() ...

Please update the last line of your PHP code to:

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

Now you should get the data you want as response.

EDIT: @1nsan3, you asked in the comment if echo not does the same as var_dump() ... I think you get an answer here: [What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

EDIT2:

Please remove the JSON.parse() call. The response of your AJAX request is already parsed by jQuery when using `dataType : 'json'`,
 as explained in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: i change json_encode($json) to echo json_encode($json) but console.log show nothing :/

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure your php returns valid json data ?

php

```
$id = $calendar->getId();
$json = array('id' => $id);
echo json_encode($json);         <-- your php code must echo only this valid json, 
return;                              make sure no other values are echoed 
                                     above or below this which will break json.
```

js

```
success : function(data) {
  if($.trim(data) != '') {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log('no data');
  }
}
```

Comment: i add that in my code but i can't see any change. i have nothing in my console! the both console.log() not working ?!

Comment: There's no need to use parseJSON() if you define the dataType as json. Please read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: jQuery parses the incoming data when you specify the dataType. Parsing it again is an error (that you didn't fix)

Comment: Are you sure you want to `$.trim` an object? What would that do?