# Display even & odd numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying loop through an array of random numbers if the the number is dividable by two then it's even and I then want to assign this to an array $even[], and if odd then assign it to the odd array. I have managed to display the results without using an array but for the sake of this I want to put them into their own array. However I can't seem to get this result I'm after all I get is this error: message Array to string conversion.

```
<?php

$numbers = array();

for ($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++) {
   $numbers[]=mt_rand(1,1000);
   if ($i % 2 == 0){
    $even[]=$i;
  } else {
    $odd[]=$i;
  }
}

echo $even;
echo $odd;

?>
```

Comment: change `echo` to `print_r($even)`

Comment: Thanks. Why would it not display with echo ?

Comment: [What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

Comment: Because `$even` and `$odd` are `array`, not `string`.

Comment: Because you shouldn't `echo` non-scalars.

Comment: Oh how would you go about achieving this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to echo the results.

```
foreach ($even as $evens){
echo $evens . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define $odd and $even as a array
 $even = array();
 $odd = array();
check if($i%2 == 0)
   {
      $even[] = $i;
   }
   else
   {
      $odd = $i;
   }
```

var_dump($even);
    var_dump($odd);