# PHP: How do I echo the results of this array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$header_content = array();
$header_content['pageone'][] = array(
    'image' => 'photo-one.png',
    'desc'  => "One. Some text here.",
);
$header_content['pagetwo'][] = array(
    'image' => 'photo-two.png',
    'desc'  => "Two. Some text here.",
);
```

I do not want to echo the entire array, just certain parts when called... like `$header_content['pageone']['image']`, except this doesn't work... How do you go about echoing parts of an array?

I have searched but it's all a little confusing right now for me. Thanks.

Comment: To print array details use print_r($header_content['pageone']);

Comment: `$header_content['pageone'][0]['image']` or remove the `[]` in your declaration

Comment: ^@Rizier123 's answer is perfect but if you want to check how your array looks like you can use `print_r` or `var_dump()` for your array_structure

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the additional `[]`, makes a lot of sense now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it like -

```
$header_content['pagetwo'] = array(
'image' => 'photo-two.png',
'desc'  => "Two. Some text here.",
);
```

The keys are different `pageone`, `pagetwo`. No need of that extra index i think. And then access it - `echo $header_dontent['pagetwo']['image'];`

Comment: That does make more sense, not sure why I was adding an extra index actually

Answer (score 1):

For printing array values, you can use :

[print_r function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Example : print_r($array)
Specific key data can be accessed through : print_r($array[$key])

**OR**

[var_dump function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Example : var_dump($array)
Specific key data can be accessed through : var_dump($array[$key])

Comment: so what is the difference between echoing an array value and using print_r?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

use it like `$header_content['pageone'][0]['image']`
Since

> $header_content['pageone'][] = array();

`[]` appends an element at the end of an array.