# Put the value of for loop inside array

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to reate an array that contains all the odd numbers between `1` to `20,000`. I Use the `var_dump()` at the end to display the array values without using loops.

For some reason it won't work out.

here's my code so far:

```
$array_variable = array();

for($i=1; $i<=20000; $i++){
    if($i%2 == 1){ // if the remainder after division `$i` by 2 is one{
        print_r($array_variable[$i]); // if odd, echo it out and then echo newline for better readability;
    }
}

var_dump($array_variable);
```

Comment: you didn't assign the value to the variable?

Comment: You're trying to display it without loops, but display it in your `for` loop anyway? Also, why are you trying to access `$array_variable[$i]` in an empty array before adding anything in?

Comment: Simple assignment problem.

Answer (score 9):

You need to push the values to your array first:

```
$array_variable = array();
for($i=1; $i<=20000; $i++){
   if($i%2 == 1){ 
       $array_variable[] = $i;// or array_push($array_variable, $i);
   }
}
var_dump($array_variable);
```

Otherwise your array stays empty.

Answer (score 6):

This results in alot of undefined indexes because you're not adding anything to `$array_variable`.

Change the code to this:

```
   $array_variable = array();

    for($i=1; $i<=20000; $i++){
      if($i%2 == 1){ // if the remainder after division `$i` by 2 is one{
        $array_variable[] = $i; // $array_variable[] means adding something to the array
      }
    }

    var_dump($array_variable); //dump all odd numbers
```

For better readability of the array you could use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_variable);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $array_variable is empty because you never add any elements to it. Try this instead:

```
$array_variable = range(1, 20000, 2);
```

Comment: range() is a PHP function that generates an array if you give it the start value, the end value, and optionally the increment step. See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 0):

$array_variable = array();

```
for($i=1; $i<=20000; $i++){
  if($i%2 == 1){ // if the remainder after division `$i` by 2 is one{
      array_push($array_variable, $i); //Push the variable into array
  }
}

var_dump($array_variable); //dump all odd numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print an element it does not exist since the array is empty.
If you insist on using an array use this code, you notice you assign a value to the array elements: ( and also if you want to display it on a new line in browser, use echo commented out): (if interested about more: [what is the difference between echo and print_r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

```
<?php 

        $array_variable = array();

        for($i=1; $i<=20000; $i++){
            $array_variable[$i]=$i;//assignment
            if($i%2 == 1){ // if the remainder after division `$i` by 2 is one{
            print_r($array_variable[$i]); // if odd, echo it out and then echo newline for better readability;
            //echo $array_variable[$i].'<br>';
        }
    }

        var_dump($array_variable);
    ?>
```