# On echo return string, on print_r return array or object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, object, echo

Some functions I have used return a string on echo, something like this.

```
echo my_function();
```

This prints "`hello`" on the screen.

```
print_r( my_function() );
```

This prints an array or an object on the screen. The function is the same in both cases, even the possible in parameters.

How is this done?

### The possible function

```
function my_function() {
    // If this function is used by echo return the string
    // If this function is used by print_r return an array

    $string = 'Hello';
    $array = array('some', 'data');

    // return $string or $array depending on
}
```

### Real life example

This function return an image on echo and an object on print_r: http://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/helpers/thumb

Comment: Post your function too whats within it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between echo, print, and print\_r in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

Comment: @Uchiha I added a function to my question.

Comment: But what you were returning over here

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to add a parameter to the function that specifies the way its called

Comment: I added a real life example

Comment: I thought that you wanted to write a function to do that, i may be wrong but it seems to me that the function returns always the same no matter what, what i think is happening is that the function returns a class with a special property or method to be treated differently depending on the usage, and is this returned object what acts different depending the case not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_function()` is not returning anything. So calling it in `echo` or `print_r` makes no diffrence. If you `return` `string` form the function and you want to just display it then you can `echo` it out. But if you `return` `array` from function and `echo` it then it will give you a **unusful output**. On the other hand if you `print_r` the function and function return string, then it will output just like echo do. But if you return array and call with `print_r` then it will show the `array` more **readable**. It is useful for debugging.

Here is more about **echo** and **print_r()**

**echo**

1. Outputs one or more strings separated by commas
2. No return value

**print_r()**

1. Outputs a human-readable representation of any one value
2. Accepts not just strings but other types including arrays and objects, formatting them to be readable
3. Useful when debugging
4. May return its output as a return value (instead of echoing) if the second optional argument is given

Answer (score -1):

Functions should never depend on who they called, but how they are called.

There is no sense in for example creating a function that does addition on echo and subtraction on print. That is confusing.

try to use parameters as suggested in the question's comments.

Comment: This function return an image on echo and an object on print_r: http://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/helpers/thumb