# Get the value of a key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable and when I output it with `print_r` like this:

```
print_r($sort_order[$field->name]);
```

I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sort_order] => 92 ) )
```

but I only need the value which is 92. How can I do so it outputs only that when echoing it? example:

```
echo $sort_order[$field->name];
```

should output simple

```
92
```

Comment: Exactly as you have it. `echo $array_name["sort_order"];`

Comment: And whats the $array_name?

Comment: What ever the name of your array is. Your post is slightly confusing. You are using `print_r` on a variable called `$sort_order`, yet the results of the print_r show an array key called `sort_order`. If this is actual correct (in that you have an array variable called `$sort_order` as well as an array key called `$sort_order`, then you would be using `echo $sort_order["sort_order"];`

Comment: My array is $sort_order. So should it be $sort_order["sort_order"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$sortOrder` array is actually an array of arrays, like:

```
[
    [ 'sort_order' => 92 ]
]
```

That's why you can't print it like you expect.

Try:

```
echo $sort_order[0]['sort_order'];
```

Output:

```
92
```

Comment: Oh, nevermind, this was the solution after all, I had ane rror somewhere else and after fixing that it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The print_r() function is used to print human-readable information about a variable.

You can do both print and echo to output the required value:

```
echo $sort_order[$field->name];

print $sort_order[$field->name];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The differences are small: echo has no return value while print has a return value of 1 so it can be used in expressions. echo can take multiple parameters (although such usage is rare) while print can take one argument.

Comment: Your field  is actually an array of arrays. So you have to access the element by its index.

Answer (score 0):

The command `print_r` displays the variable in a human readable way. So if you need to know all the info in a variable (in particular for large arrays), then you use that. For other use, e.g. when you only need to know the content (in I guess 99.999% of all the cases) you should either use `echo` as you already mentioned it or `print` (althoug, they are more or less the same).

Please consider this links for futher information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

[What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)