# PHP $_post array always follow a number "1"

Tags: php, arrays, http-post

```
<form  name="form1" method="post" action="test2.php"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>


 <?php
    echo print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

The code shows `Array () 1` or `Array ( [checkbox1] => on [textbox1] => asf [submit] => submit ) 1`.

I don't understand why does the array always follows the number `1`.

When I change `POST` method to `GET` method, the same thing happen.

When I use another Array to store the value of `$_POST`, the same thing happen again!

```
<?php
    $temp = $_POST;
    if (isset($_POST['textbox1']))
    $temp = "textbox1='{$temp['textbox1']}'";

    textbox1='asdf'1
    Array ( [textbox1] => asdf [submit] => submit) 1
?>
```

Comment: There must be something in your page outputting the '1' Have you checked for hidden characters or other markup?

Comment: add die() after var_dump(use var_dump instead print_r) and show ouput

Comment: If you don't do a `print_r` do you still see that extra `1` outputted?

Comment: problem is `echo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` and `print` are similar, this is like doing `echo echo ($_POST);` to give you an example (which would give you an error). 
Remove `echo` and leave only `print_r($_POST);`.

Also, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php) on differences between `echo`, `print` and `print_r`.

Comment: To be exact: `print_r` function (without second parameter set) prints its argument directly to stdout. It **ALSO** returns a value (`true`). So, what you were doing, you were first printing out variable contents to stdout, and THEN echo'ing return value of `print_r` function (`true`, mapped to `1` by `echo`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<form  name="form1" method="post" action="test2.php"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>


 <?php
    print_r($_POST);  // Remove echo 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !!