# What is the difference between print_r and echo when providing results to an AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

Although I have found some discussion about the general differences between echo and print_r() in PHP (for example, [What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)), all the tutorials and answers I've come across for AJAX calls say PHP should *echo* the results, and then die.

In an experiment returning a simple string, I didn't see any difference between the two when displayed using console.log.

Is there any significant difference in what is returned to the AJAX call when using echo vs print_r. Not that I see anything wrong with using echo, but I did get unexpected results when I used print_r earlier in the function for debugging.

Comment: print and echo are more or less synonyms - they simply output a string whereas print_r will allow you to print out an array/object/other to give a visual clue when debugging more than anything

Comment: If your AJAX is expecting json (common), using print_r will certainly mangle your output.

Comment: @Randall So, yes, there is a difference in what is returned? Is this because, as the linked answer states, echo can handle multiple strings while print_r is limited to one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common built-in output functions in PHP are: [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php), [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), and [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). They are all designed to output data, albeit, in slightly different ways. Which is why there are specific use cases associated with each function.

- **echo**: The most notorious. It's what you should be using to output data to an AJAX caller. It's simple and effective. It's actually a language construct, so it doesn't require you to use brackets. You just write `echo 'string';` or `echo $something;`, etc.

  *It also supports multiple comma-delimited values, making it handy in a variety of use cases; e.g., `echo 'string1', 'string2', 'string3';`. Note that **echo** returns `null` (nothing).*

---

- **print**: Also a language construct, it's nearly the same as **echo**, with the difference being that it accepts only one argument and always returns the same thing: `1`. It's OK to use **print** instead of **echo** if you like, but many popular PHP projects have code standards that ask you not to do so. So **print** has become, more or less, an unused (or *rarely* used) function in PHP.

---

- **printf**: This function and its brother [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) are designed to output formatted strings. It's slightly more complex, but does have specific use cases. For example, these are often used to output an integer as a binary number or octal number, for translation, among many other options that are well documented at PHP.net — that's a separate topic.

---

- **print_r**, **var_dump**, and **var_export**: These are most commonly used when debugging code or testing code in one way or another. You will *rarely* find a use case for them in production code. That said, these allow you to pass in complex data types, such as an entire array, and **print_r** recursively, to dump the entire array for analysis. **var_dump** does pretty much the same thing, but uses a slightly different approach that can sometimes be useful. **var_export** has the advantage of outputting a parseable string.

  ***print_r*** and **var_export** both support a parameter that can 'return' the value it would normally output, which can be a handy feature. Something that **var_dump** is not capable of.

Comment: I acknowledge I did not directly ask why echo is a better choice (assuming it is), and I appreciate that you alluded to it. Any more reasons why echo is what we should use? @Randall alluded to print_r garbling output, but if I understand echo, it is actually only useful for the simplest of returns?

Comment: Quite welcome. `echo` is useful for nearly all output that you'll do in PHP. If you're outputting something and you're _not_ using `echo`, you'll have a very good reason for doing so, and it will be a special case; e.g., you'll be using `printf()` or `echo sprintf()` for something special. In all other cases, you output with `echo` as a best practice. Or, you can think of it this way: the 'format' is generally being handled by your script. When it's time to output, you `echo`. The format has already been established elsewhere.

Comment: If the `echo` function were named `output`, it would probably be less confusing, because that's _all_ it does. Nothing more. It's just outputting something that has already been formatted. The same with `print`.

Comment: I wouldn't say `print_r` garbles output, I'd say that it outputs data for analysis, which can look like gobbly-goop to a user. However, it's in a specific format that's primarily intended for developer consumption. The same with `var_dump` and `var_export`.